# Events and COM Add-in like operations in Outlook-Web add ins

Tags: node.js, outlook, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create an outlook web add-in using Node.js in which I am trying to do the following things:

> 1. make an API call on receiving email
> 2. label emails
> 3. move emails to spam
> 4. get all emails of a specific folder

Is this possible? If Yes then how? Please give me the links to any documentation or tutorials for the same.

These things, I am able to do in the desktop VSTO COM add-in for the desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developing an add-in for outlook please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/

1. Make an API call on receiving email: Using the current add-in api set available this is not possible.
2. label emails: Categories API is available in the preview version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.categories?view=office-js
3. Move emails to spam: You can use MS Graph API in the add-in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs
4. Get all emails of a specific folder: Please refer to MS Graph API for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Comment: is there any other way like o365 API or any other API to make an API call on receiving a new email in inbox or a particular folder? @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT